# TypeScript: declare constructor on global window

Tags: typescript

I am trying to declare an expected constructor on the window object.

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    MyApi: {
      MyClassType: any
    }
  }
}

expect(new window.MyApi.MyClassType()).toNotBe(undefined)
```

What should `any` be?

Comment: create your own class and that will be simply the name of the class. and then window.MyApi = { MyClassType: new MyClassType() }

Answer (score 2):

It should be the type of your class, e.g.

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    MyApi: {
      MyClassType: MyClass;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I don't have access to the runtime impl of the class? i.e. basically I want a .d.ts for my class type.

Answer (score 1):

A nice thing about typescript is that you can use class as types

So in your case make your class

```
class MyClass {}
```

And in declaration

```
MyClassType: MyClass
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `window.MyApi.MyClassType` to be your class/constructor and not an instance. If you wanted it to be an instance, then you could use `MyClassType` as the type. Otherwise you need `typeof MyClassType`.

But to get it working right, if you want to use the `declare global` syntax you need to make sure that the file where that is declared needs to contain at least one `import` or `export` otherwise you'll get an error "Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations."

Here's a working example:

```
class MyClassType {
    // Your class implementation
}
export default MyClassType;

window.MyApi = {
  MyClassType: MyClassType,
};

declare global {
  interface Window {
    MyApi: {
      MyClassType: typeof MyClassType;
    };
  }
}
```

But this is also another possibility in case you don't want the file to have any imports or exports:

```
class MyClassType {
    // Your class implementation
}

declare var MyApi: { // eslint-disable-line
  MyClassType: typeof MyClassType;
};

window.MyApi = {
  MyClassType: MyClassType,
};
```

These let you access the API like so:

```
import './my-api';
const foo = new window.MyApi.MyClassType();
```